# What is the logic in "more than one + singular noun/verb"?

Tags: grammar, logic

> More than one **game** **was** lost.

The singular form confused me.

Does "more than one" here indicate plural or "more than" itself emphasis some quality?

How should I parse this sentence to make sense?

Comment: I'm not sure it's *logic* as much as *convention*, to match the verb to the noun in the idiomatic expression.  Note you can also say, *More than a few **games were** lost.*

Answer (score 2):

Start with the simple case:

> One game was lost.

This conforms to standard usage, singular **game**, singular **was**.

Now we want to say that not only a single game was lost, a likely context being that we are evaluating the success of a team, or a coach.

> Losing one game might be bad luck, but more than one game was lost, this is not good.

We are treating **more than** as a modifier of the original **one game was lost**.